# Помогите с рандомом Python

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Вообщем нужно было сделать что бы зеленая то-есть stavka3 выпадала с очень маленькой вероятностью, это я вроде понял и написал, но встал вопрос, если пользователь поставил на черную или красную как сделать что бы выбирал 50/50 и если ставка совпадет то что он ввел выйгрыш

```
if (cmd.lower().startswith("рулетка")):
        try:
            c, i, a = cmd.lower().split()
            i = str(i)
            a = int(a)
        except ValueError:
            self.current.remove(msg.user_id)

            return await msg.answer(" .азино рулетка [цвет] (черный, красный, зеленый) [ставка] - сыграть в рулетку на указанную сумму.")   

        except Exception:
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc()

            self.current.remove(msg)
            return await msg.answer("Произошла ошибка.")

        if i == "черный" or i == "чёрный":
            stavka = 1
            vivod = ""
        elif i == "красный":
            stavka = 2
            vivod = "❤"
        elif i == "зеленый" or i == "зелёный":
            stavka = 3
            vivod = ""
        elif i == i:
            return await msg.answer(" Ты ввел неверный цвет доступные цвета (черный, красный, зеленый)")                               

        bett = a

        if bett < self.min_bet:
            self.current.remove(msg.user_id)
            return await msg.answer(" Минимальная ставка: 5.00$")

        if bett > 10000000:
            self.current.remove(msg.user_id)
            return await msg.answer(" Ставка, не больше чем 10.000.000$.")    

        if p.balance - bett < 0:
            self.current.remove(msg.user_id)
            return await msg.answer(f" У вас не хватает средств!\n Наличные: {round(p.balance, 2)}$")    

        p, _ = await self.pwmanager.get_or_create(self.player, user_id=msg.user_id)

        bot = random.randrange(1, 100)

        text = ""

        vivod2 = ""        

        if stavka == 1 and bot == 1:
            text += f"➕ Тебе повезло! Ты выбрал {vivod}, и я выбрала {vivod}, ты получаешь " + str(bett * 2) + "$ (x2)"

            p.balance += bett * 2
        elif stavka == 2 and bot == 2:
            text += f"➕ Тебе повезло! Ты выбрал {vivod}, и я выбрала {vivod}, ты получаешь " + str(bett * 2) + "$ (x2)"

            p.balance += bett * 2
        elif stavka == 3 and bot <= 5:
            vivod2 = ""
            text += f"➕ Тебе повезло! Ты выбрал {vivod}, и я выбрала {vivod}, ты получаешь " + str(bett * 3) + "$ (x3)"

            p.balance += bett * 3
        else:    
            text += f"➖ Ха! Тебе не повезло! Ты выбрал {vivod}, а я выбрала {vivod2}, ты теряешь " + str(bett) + "$"

            p.balance -= bett

        text += f"\n Наличные: {round(p.balance, 2)}$"    


        await self.pwmanager.update(p)
        self.current.remove(msg.user_id)

        return await msg.answer(text)
```

Comment: Уберите части кода, которые не нужны для решения задачи (например, те, где выводятся символы, и некоторые другие). Они ничего не добавляют, а только отнимают внимание и время.

Comment: ``elif i == i`` - это о чем?

Comment: Это типо если пользователь ввел не тот цвет который сверху, то выводит текст хд, извините за этот плохой код, просто я тут недельку)